# Iron Router and post.find() conditions from the database

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've been trying to find a way to dynamically throw in a find() condition that comes from the database through Iron Router and a controller, is this possible? For example:

```
.. ..

HomeController = PostsListController.extend({
data: function() {
    return {
        posts: Posts.find({ likeDrinks: {$in: ['soda','juice']} }, this.findOptions()),
    };
}

});

.. ..
```

The above code works as something static. The **['soda','juice']** part is what I want to come from the database, particularly from the Meteor.user() object and in the .profile.likesSoda property. Basically, I want to filter results based on values saved in the user's profile. Unfortunately, I haven't been having much luck. When I do use Meteor.user() or Meteor.users.findOne( _id: Meteor.userId()), they're initially undefined (and eventually something comes up) so they cause errors.

Any idea why Meteor.userId() is readily accessible vs. Meteor.user() within the data() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data` function runs inside a reactive computation, so it will be rerun whenever Posts.find is changed or Meteor.user() is changed. 
Below example shows how to safely run Posts.find without worry about undefined issue.

```
data:function(){
  var user = Meteor.user();
  var likesSoda = user && user.profile && user.profile.likesSoda;
  if(likesSoda){
  return   {
             posts: Posts.find({ likeDrinks: {$in: likesSoda} }, this.findOptions()),
           };
  }else{
    return {posts:[]};
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah dude, that's awesome! It finally works without throwing me any of those app breaking errors.